# How can I successfully capture all possible cases to create a python list from a text file

Tags: python, string, list, parsing, python-2.7

[This public gist](https://gist.github.com/ColtonPhillips/2e74c870a0be91d4c60f) creates a simple scenario where you can turn a text file into a python list line by line.

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as listFile:
        lines = listFile.read().split("\n")

out = []
for item in lines:
        if '"' in item:
                out.append('("""' + item + '"""),')
        else:
                out.append('("' + item + '"),')

with open('out.py', 'a') as outFile:
        outFile.write("out = [\n")
        for item in out:
                outFile.write("\t" + item + "\n")
        outFile.write("]")
```

In `text.txt` the sixth and seventh lines

```
'"""'
""
```

are the ones that produce invalid output. Perhaps you can think of some other examples that would fail to work.

EDIT:

Valid output would look something like this:

```
out = [
"line1",
"line2",
""" line 3 has """ and "" and " in it """, # but it is a valid string
"last line",
]
```

The ( and ) characters were an oversight by me they are not needed or wanted...

EDIT: Oh god I'm getting overwhelmed. I'm going to take 5 minutes and post the question again in a better form.

Comment: A much easier way to turn a text file into a list of lines is: `with open('test.txt') as f: lines = list(f)`.

Comment: Meanwhile, what is this other code supposed to be doing? What does "invalid output" mean? You haven't even defined what you want the output to be.

Comment: Is your goal to understand how Python parses lines on input (pretty easy) and how it `repr`s lists (more involved, but still not really _hard_), or just to read in lines and write out a Python list display of those lines?

Comment: The goal is to take a list of strings that you make casually ( or maybe a non programmer has made ) and turn them all into a list of strings inside a python list.

Comment: Or, if your question is why your code doesn't work, I can explain why it _can't_ work, whatever it's trying to do: If any input is legal, quoting is never sufficient; you need escaping. One usually-readable way to do that is by backslash escaping (at least) the quotes and backslashes, then quoting. Another way is to "double up" quotes so you end up with separate strings that get concatenated together. (In Python, `'"' "Filet O'Fish" '"'` is evaluated as the string `"Filet O'Fish"`.)

Comment: First, that's still too vague to understand. Give us some actual input and desired output, and the actual rule, not just a vague description of it. Second, edit your question to make it stand on its own, don't just try to follow up with comments. Third, you've got two answers, and you haven't commented on either. Are they on the right track? If not, telling us why they don't answer your question may help clarify the question.

Comment: Is the `out = ` part of the output? If not, what does my answer not do that you want? More importantly, what is it that _makes_ that valid output? Is it because you can interpret it as Python code? Or is there more to it than that?

Comment: Don't just post the same question again; edit this question to make it clearer. (And you don't have to add "EDIT:" blocks at the end; just change the existing text. If people really want to see the history, SO preserves edit histories.)

Comment: Don't try to blank your questions. Read the Help, stop trying to fight the way the site works.

Comment: You don't have to "flag for deletion" (indeed, just commenting that won't do anything) - if you really want to, [*delete it yourself*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179493/248731).

Comment: I can only  delete the duplicate of this post. I am barred from deleting it because it "has answers"

Comment: Did you not get the answer you wanted? Why can't you just edit the question into a coherent question and accept the answer, or explain why the answer is wrong? Why do you keep trying to screw everything up?

Comment: The question itself is wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using a [newline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations) character besides `\n` would also cause the program to fail. In Windows its common to use `\r` or `\r\n`.

@abarnert's comment shows a better way to read lines.

Comment: You can deal with the newlines by just opening the file in `rU` mode. (Or using `io.open` to do it the easier Python3 way.)

Comment: If I use @arbarnerts solution (which is nice) in this case it appends a new line to each line of the input This is not ideal because the whole point of the script is to apply " characters to each end of each line in order to make a list of strings

Answer (score -1):

A text file is already an iterable of lines.

As with any other iterable, you can convert it to a list by just passing it to the `list` constructor:

```
with open('text.txt') as f:
    lines = list(f)
```

Or, if you don't want the newlines on the end of each line:

```
with open('text.txt') as f:
    lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]
```

If you want to handle classic Mac and Windows line endings as well as Unix, open the file in universal-newlines mode:

```
with open('text.txt', 'rU') as f:
```

… or use the Python 3-style `io` classes (but note that this will give you `unicode` strings, not byte strings, which will repr with `u` prefixes—they're still valid Python literals that way, but they won't look as pretty):

```
import io
with io.open('text.txt') as f:
```

---

Now, it's hard to tell from code that doesn't work and no explanation of what's wrong with it, but it looks like you're trying to figure out how to write that list out as a Python-source-format list display, wrapping it in brackets, adding quotes, escaping any internal quotes, etc. But there's a much easier way to do that too:

```
with open('out.py', 'a') as f:
    f.write(repr(lines))
```

---

If you're trying to pretty-print it, there's a `pprint` module in the stdlib for exactly that purpose, and various bigger/better alternatives on PyPI. Here's an example of the output of `pprint.pprint(lines, width=60)` with (what I think is) the same input you used for your desired output:

```
['line1',
 'line2',
 ' line 3 has """ and "" and " in it ',
 'last line']
```

Not exactly the same as your desired output—but, unlike your output, it's a valid Python list display that evaluates to the original input, and it looks pretty readable to me.

Comment: I'm trying to take a text file and turn each line into an element of a list where the character " is essentially added to each side of the line thusly making a list of strings. I'm sorry for the mediocre question. Really, awful on my part.

Comment: @IamPolaris: Just adding `"` to each side doesn't make it a string literal, unless there are no `"` characters in the string. And your examples prove that there _can_ be `"` characters in the string. But calling `repr` on a string _always_ gives you a valid string literal. And calling either `str` or `repr` on a list calls `repr` on each of its members. So… is there something wrong with that?